# Instance pointer differs from vfptr when .dll is loaded

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, memory-address, virtual-table

So, I was playing around with Visual Studio's Test Suite and I discovered something interesting:

I have an instance to class A at address, say, `0x0656a64c`.
Then when I watched over the variable, it says that its `__vfptr` is pointing at `0x077e7c0c`.

As far as I know, a class' virtual table pointer should be located in the first 4 bytes (or 8 bytes on 64-bit applications) of the class instance, unless it's a case of multiple inheritance (then it's just offsets of the 1st vtable address).

I observed that Visual Studio compiled my test into a .dll and run its test tools dynamically loading the .dll.

Could this be what's causing the address difference?

Here's a screenshot of the VS debugger

[image: Difference in addresses]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the address of the vptr, and the address that the vptr is pointing at.  You are (roughly) correct that the usual implementation is that the vptr is the first thing in the object - but Visual Studio is showing you the address of the *vtable* (which is shared between all objects of the class).

Comment: Ahh, yeah, I misinterpreted those values for sure. Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

This is just normal behavior for MS C++ compiler. 2 DLL's that create instances of the same class objects will have different vtables. Intuition would says the vtable should be shared with all instances regardless of what DLL's code created (new) it. It should be common to the implementation of the class. Not true.

This creates a danger when a DLL is released dynamically. All objects allocated may still be in valid (Process) heap. But, if it has a virtual destructor then that is defined in the vtable. It is now in freed space. So the vtable is corrupt. Any use of it will generate exception.

The solution is to clean up any/all allocations made by the dynamic DLL that might also have a vtable (e.g. virtual destructor) before freeing the DLL. Any allocations made in process heap that dont point to a DLL based vtable are fine. Worste case is a memory leak if not properly tracked.